# Filter each column by having the same value three times or more

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Data set that contains Dates as an index, and each column is the name of an item with count as value. I'm trying to figure out how to filter each column where there will be more than 3 consecutive days where the count is zero for each different column. I was thinking of using a for loop, any help is appreciated. I'm using python for this project.

I'm fairly new to python, so far I tried using for loops, but did not get it to work in any way.

```
for i in a.index:
    if a.loc[i,'name']==3==df.loc[i+1,'name']==df.loc[i+2,'name']:
        print(a.loc[i,"name"])
```

Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without freq.

Comment: Please provide a sample data (in text form) and expected output. That would help your question get answered *much more* quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you included a sample dataframe and desired output in your question. Please do the next time. This way, I have to guess what your data looks like and may not be answering your question. I assume the values are integers. Does your dataframe have a row for every day? I will assume that might not be the case. I will make it so that every day in the last *delta* days has a row. I created a sample dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# Here I am just creating random data from your description
delta = 365
start_date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=delta)
end_date = datetime.datetime.now()
datetimes = [end_date - diff for diff in [datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(delta,0,-1)]]
# This is the list of dates we will have in our final dataframe (includes all days)
dates = pd.Series([date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for date in datetimes], name='Date', dtype='datetime64[ns]')
# random integer dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(delta,4)), columns=['item' + str(i) for i in range(4)])
df = pd.concat([df, dates], axis=1).set_index('Date')
# Create a missing day
df = df.drop(df.loc['2019-08-01'].name)
# Reindex so that index has all consecutive days
df = df.reindex(index=dates)
```

Now that we have a sample dataframe, the rest will be straightforward. I am going to check if a value in the dataframe is equal to 0 and then do a [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) sum with the window of 4 (>3). This way I can avoid for loops. The resulting dataframe has all the rows where at least one of the items had a value of 0 for 4 consecutive rows. If there is a 0 for more than *window* consecutive rows, it will show as two rows where the dates are just one day apart. I hope that makes sense.

```
# custom function as I want "np.nan" returned if a value does not equal "test_value" 
def equals(df_value, test_value=0):
    return 1 if df_value == test_value else np.nan
# apply the function to every value in the dataframe
# for each row, calculate the sum of four subsequent rows (>3)
df = df.applymap(equals).rolling(window=4).sum()
# if there was np.nan in the sum, the sum is np.nan, so it can be dropped
# keep the rows where there is at least 1 value
df = df.dropna(thresh=1)
# drop all columns that don't have any values
df = df.dropna(thresh=1, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I just started coding and using Stackoverflow, so I'm sure on how to ask questions, This definitely helped a lot. Another question, is it true that I should avoid using loops on the dataframe analysis?

Comment: I'm ok with spending more time on explaining and answering if I see someone is new. I don't want to discourage anyone. My point is that a good question leads to better answers in shorter time. Re: for loops, if using pandas, it is good practice not to iterate over dataframes. Pandas use cython and vectorized operations under the hood. Avoiding for loops is going to make your code a lot more efficient and it is a good habit to develop for when you work with larger datasets.